# function pointer

Tags: c

What is the difference between these two statements:

```
void (*p) (void *a[],int n)
```

and

```
void *(*p[]) (void *a, int n)
```

Comment: http://cdecl.org/

Comment: so both are syntactical erroneous?

Comment: i dont think so..can you give some reason..

Comment: @Robert, @prp - cdecl is an odd tool, and perhaps I should have offered some more explanation. For cdecl to parse these declarations, you need to type `explain` in front of it, and remove the names of the arguments (a practice I do with function pointers anyway, but which C should normally parse perfectly fine). cdecl doesn't like them for no good reason I know of, but will give you the right answer if you take them out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ cdecl
void (*p) (void *a[],int n);
declare p as pointer to function that expects (a as array of pointer to void, n as int) returning void;
void *(*p[]) (void *a, int n);
declare p as array of pointer to function that expects (a as pointer to void, n as int) returning pointer to void;
```

Comment: Does your cdecl handle parameter names, or did you just edit the I/O to be nicer to read? And if the former, where can I find a copy of this?

Answer (score 2):

there is beautiful way of comprehending such type of complex declaration in Expert_C_Programming_Deep_C_Secrets_by_Peter_van_der_Linden on page 71.

According to him :

Declarations in c are boustrophedonically, i.e alternating right-to-left with left-to-right.
Have a look at this snapshot

[image: How-to-read-c-declaration]

The ebook is available on google if you know how to download it.

Answer (score 0):

void (*p) (void *a[],int n)
p is the variable name. Remove p from the above line
void ( * )(void *a[],int n) . So p is of this type. This is a pointer of a function. So p is a pointer to the function with that signature.
So p is a pointer to a function which return void and  takes array of 'void pointers' and int as the parameter.

void *(*p[]) (void *a, int n)
[] has more precedence than *.  So p is an array. remove p[] the above.
So p is an array of void( * )(void *a[],int n)

So here p is an array of pointers to function which return void and  takes array of 'void pointers' and int as the parameter.

Comment: Please stop linking to your website in your answers. Your answer should be as succinct as possible, adding a self-promoting link adds nothing to the answer.